# How do I create a Windows 8.1 bootable usb stick in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows, 15.10

I've already partitioned my hard drive and have my iso. I can't download Winusb, UNetbootin doesn't work, and neither does startup disk creator. I've tried Rufus and Microsoft's official usb tools through Wine and nothing has worked. Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you've booted in Ubuntu, you can use `dd`. In a teminal, type

sudo dd if=input.iso of=/dev/sdX

where `input.iso` is the source windows iso and `/dev/sdX` (X will vary) is the destination USB drive **you want to wipe** entirely and replace with the windows iso. I use `gparted` to make sure I'm writing to the device I think I'm writing to, as **`dd` will nuke whatever you point it at**.

Comment: I did that and got, "dd: failed to open 'Computer/home/gaahl/Downloads/windows/windows.iso': No such file or directory. Do I need to go back to my root folder?

Comment: Just for simplicity, I'd move the windows .iso into your `~/`  first, then your input file would be `windows.iso` rather than `/home/gaahl/Downloads/windows/windows.iso`. One less place for a simple typing error. Have you checked your windows.iso to make sure it's really what you think it is? Can you mount it and see the directory structure and files inside?